# How to see actual SQL expression generated by LINQ-to-SQL in Visual Studio 2008 during debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, debugging, intellisense

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't provide me the generated SQL expression through IntelliSense by the simple act of hovering my mouse over the System.Data.Linq.DataQuery<..> variable. (However 2010 does).

When I'm working in VS 2008 is there an easy way to see the generated SQL expression without resorting to MS SQL Server Profiler or an external tool?  I want to see it during a debug session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install this plugin.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yup, use set [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property to a `TextWriter` which you want to receive the query information.

(You could easily set it to a `StringWriter` if you're debugging - or in a console app I usually just use `Console.Out`.)